# Mysql2::Error: Table .schema_migrations' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, mysql2

I just started mining.
while i'm trying to setup (and follow the instructions to do that, command - rake db:migration)  following error occurred. The article i followed http://angular-rails.com/bootstrap.html

"Mysql2::Error: Table 'amweb_development.schema_migrations' doesn't exist: SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`"

Can i  re-configure mysql2 ? will that solve my problem? or is there any other way, i don't have any data in my database, so i can recreate everything.

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you create the database?

Comment: using sequel pro tool

Comment: if the db is still empty, try runnung `rake db:drop` then `rake db:create`

Answer (score 1):

How is your database.yml file setup?  I had this same problem and it was due to using a database other than the standard production, test, and development. You can create the schema_migrations table yourself, or you can do it with a rake task.  The key if you are using rake is to specify the environment (essentially the name of your database).

if your database.yml file has an entry like such:

```
amweb_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: amweb_development
```

then the rake task to setup the database (including the schema migrations table) would be:

```
rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=amweb_development
```